# Auto-populating Model with user information for all @Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, openid, spring-roo

I have a unique problem I am trying to solve with a Spring Roo-built site that I recently added OpenID support for.  I [posted something on the Spring Forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127999-Output-UserDetails-properties-in-JSPX-with-support-for-form-and-OpenID-login), and tried to describe the problem to the best of my ability, but so far I haven't received any help.

Here is the synopsis, as best I can describe it.  The site I am working on had a simple form login, using Spring Security and the JDBCUserDetailsService.  We also wanted users the ability to login via a supported OpenID, so using the [Spring Security examples for implementing OpenID w/ auto-registration](http://git.springsource.org/~ltaylor/spring-security/lukes-spring-security/blobs/ee1fd1bc50a7232617a4668c4fcd450958cab437/samples/openid/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/openid/CustomUserDetailsService.java) we modified our site code to allow both simple form AND OpenID login.  The UserDetails is still coming from the database, the only difference being that the OpenID userid is the full authentication url string passed back from the OpenID provider.

The problem I am running into is in our header code.  We had some simple JSPX code that did the following:

```
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal == null}">
      <span>
        <form method="post" action="${login}" name="login_form" id="login_form">
          <input name="j_username" type="text" id="j_username" />
          <input name="j_password" type="password" id="j_password" />
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="proceed" />
        </form>
      </span>
      <span>or <a href="${registration_form}">Register</a></span>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <span>Hello, <a href="${user_profile_base}${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal.name}"><img src="${user_img_url}" width='10' height='10' />${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal.name}</a></span> | <a href="${logout}">Logout</a>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
```

Basically, if the user Principal is not in the page context (i.e. the user is not logged in), then display the login for, otherwise print out a nice "Welcome..." with the user's username.  This code required no special provisions in the controller code to function: Either the user was logged in or not.

Now the problem is with the OpenID users.  The username is no longer a nice, user defined string.  Instead its a long URL string that may or may not contain a user-readable ID name in it somewhere (Google, for instance, has some nebulous string that looks like a GUID).

I thought about adding an "Alias" field to the user object stored in the DB (which happens to be an instance of UserDetails, fwiw), and allowing the user to set it themselves, but I don't know how to get at that data from the JSPX-side in a "generic" way.  I know someone out there is trying to do something similar, but I haven't been able to find anything thing showing how they approached it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, for whatever reason, calls to

```
${user_profile_base}${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal
```

was returning an instance of [org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationToken](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/openid/OpenIDAuthenticationToken.html).  In reading up on the JavaDoc, I found I could get the actual Principal object first, then call my Alias getter, like so:

```
${user_profile_base}${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal.principal.alias
```

This working as expected.  I probably need to do some additional checking to make sure the Principal and alias are not null, but at least it's working now.